# Assign orders to customers where the emails are matching with a SQL query

Tags: magento2, database, orders, customer, sql

I want to reassign existing orders to customers after deleting all customers and importing them into Magento 2 from a csv. The `sales_order.customer_id` values are not matching with the correct customer anymore in the table. They have a value of NULL. But the emails are still there in `sales_order.customer_email`.

I would like a SQL query (or Magento 2 way if easier) which compares the emails if they are matching in both tables `sales_order.customer_email` and `customer_entity.email`. If the emails are matching, the SQL query should update the `sales_order.customer_id` value with the value from `customer_entity.entity_id`

Afaik after that I can just reindex to update the `sales_order_grid` table, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trying around I solved it by using the following SQL qeuery:

```
UPDATE sales_order as SFO
INNER JOIN customer_entity as C
ON C.email = SFO.customer_email
SET SFO.customer_ID = C.entity_id
WHERE SFO.customer_is_guest = 0
```